# How to maximize the dependent variable in a linear equation with fixed sum of independent variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a use-case where I need to use the linear equation to maximize the dependent variable ie Y in the linear equation, but the constraint is, the sum of independent variables ie xo, x1, x2, x3, x4 is fixed to some number Z.

```
Y = (xo + a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x3 + a4 * x4)
```

We need to maximize Y in the above equation, the slopes ie a1, a2, a3, a4 are known. But, we have a constraint that

```
xo + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = Z, where Z is known.
```

We need to find xo, x1, x2, x3, x4 such that Y is maximized. Is it possible to find?

P.S: I am not sure mathematically how to do it, all I have tried is to brute force using programming to find values of xo, x1, x2, x3, x4 where the sum is Z and Y was maximized.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Are $a$ and $x$ nonnegative?

Comment: @RobPratt "a" can be negative, but Xs are all non-negative numbers.

Comment: @PankajMishra Let $\max\{a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}=a_j$, where $a_0=1$. Then $x_j=Z$ maximize $Y$.